# Foundation 5 columns

Tags: html, css, zurb-foundation, zurb-foundation-5

I want two blocks of text to be in the same row and to take up the same space. I gave the divs classes small-6, medium-6 and large-6 (initially it was supposed to be small-12, but in hopes of fixing it I changed it to 6).

It still ends up looking like this http://prntscr.com/9ej39s and I can't seem to fix it.

```html
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/foundation/5.5.3/css/foundation.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


    <div class="row about">
        <div class="small-6 medium-6 large-6 colums panel">
            <a name="about" href="">
                <h1>About</h1>
            </a>
            <p class="justify">Bacon ipsum dolor amet spare ribs capicola cupim beef porchetta fatback kielbasa corned beef doner short loin sausage meatball boudin rump. Jerky ribeye pancetta drumstick spare ribs turducken kevin fatback tenderloin bacon prosciutto corned beef ball tip pig strip steak. Brisket tail picanha pork tenderloin, doner cupim sausage salami venison pork loin turkey tongue ham fatback. Kielbasa salami pork, turkey tongue brisket prosciutto pork belly andouille pancetta leberkas kevin frankfurter venison shankle. Strip steak ball tip venison sausage beef ribs. Tri-tip pork chop hamburger, frankfurter meatball tail flank doner pork belly.</p>
        </div>

        <div class="small-6 medium-6 large-6 colums panel">
            <a name="howtouse" href="">
                <h1>How to use?</h1>
            </a>
            <p class="justify">Bacon ipsum dolor amet spare ribs capicola cupim beef porchetta fatback kielbasa corned beef doner short loin sausage meatball boudin rump. Jerky ribeye pancetta drumstick spare ribs turducken kevin fatback tenderloin bacon prosciutto corned beef ball tip pig strip steak. Brisket tail picanha pork tenderloin, doner cupim sausage salami venison pork loin turkey tongue ham fatback. Kielbasa salami pork, turkey tongue brisket prosciutto pork belly andouille pancetta leberkas kevin frankfurter venison shankle. Strip steak ball tip venison sausage beef ribs. Tri-tip pork chop hamburger, frankfurter meatball tail flank doner pork belly.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: you spelt `columns` incorrectly - change it and you'll see

Comment: I'm really ashamed for making a mistake as stupid as this, but I guess the spelling ones are the hardest to find, right? :(
Anyway, thank you, good Sir!

Comment: @VukBibic remember to accept and/or upvote answers and comments you found helpful. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

**Answer:** The problem is that you misspelled the `columns` class.

**Sidenote:** You don't need to add `medium-6` and `large-6` classes. If you have `small-6` and all the columns up from small are going to be the same, that's all you need.

```html
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/foundation/5.5.3/css/foundation.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


    <div class="row about">
        <div class="small-6 columns panel">
            <a name="about" href="">
                <h1>About</h1>
            </a>
            <p class="justify">Bacon ipsum dolor amet spare ribs capicola cupim beef porchetta fatback kielbasa corned beef doner short loin sausage meatball boudin rump. Jerky ribeye pancetta drumstick spare ribs turducken kevin fatback tenderloin bacon prosciutto corned beef ball tip pig strip steak. Brisket tail picanha pork tenderloin, doner cupim sausage salami venison pork loin turkey tongue ham fatback. Kielbasa salami pork, turkey tongue brisket prosciutto pork belly andouille pancetta leberkas kevin frankfurter venison shankle. Strip steak ball tip venison sausage beef ribs. Tri-tip pork chop hamburger, frankfurter meatball tail flank doner pork belly.</p>
        </div>

        <div class="small-6 columns panel">
            <a name="howtouse" href="">
                <h1>How to use?</h1>
            </a>
            <p class="justify">Bacon ipsum dolor amet spare ribs capicola cupim beef porchetta fatback kielbasa corned beef doner short loin sausage meatball boudin rump. Jerky ribeye pancetta drumstick spare ribs turducken kevin fatback tenderloin bacon prosciutto corned beef ball tip pig strip steak. Brisket tail picanha pork tenderloin, doner cupim sausage salami venison pork loin turkey tongue ham fatback. Kielbasa salami pork, turkey tongue brisket prosciutto pork belly andouille pancetta leberkas kevin frankfurter venison shankle. Strip steak ball tip venison sausage beef ribs. Tri-tip pork chop hamburger, frankfurter meatball tail flank doner pork belly.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
```